# wkhtmltopdf not converting quotes and spaces properly

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am using this `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)` version of wkhtmltopdf.
With [Montserrat](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&subset=latin) font-family.

The HTML is like this,

```
<strong>
    This Agreement for home staging and rental of furniture and accessories 
</strong>
(“Agreement”) is entered this
```

Which outputs as,

> T his Agre e me nt f or home staging and re ntal of f urniture and
>   acce ssorie s (â​​ Agre e me ntâ​​ )

And,

```
<u>Services</u>&nbsp; 
Subject to the terms and conditions of this </span>
```

Which outputs as,

> Â Se rvice sÂ Subje ct to the te rms and conditions of this

Why these `Â` are comming in between?

I have tried to replace the quotes and spaces like this,

```
$formData = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $formData);
$formData = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $formData);
$formData = str_replace('“', '"', $formData);
$formData = str_replace('”', '"', $formData);
```

But didn't helped. Am I doing something wrong?
Searched, but cannot find the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Write this after head tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Comment: working for me after adding the meta tag. Tested with `wkhtmltoimage 0.12.5 (with patched qt)`

Comment: Set the setting `web.defaultEncoding` to `utf-8` should do the trick. (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/libwkhtmltox/pagesettings.html#pageWeb)